# Fixing a CSS3 Menu

Tags: html, css

I have made a pure CSS3 dropdown menu, and inserted the file into an HTML file using the **object** tag. The problem is, when I hover over the menu, a scrollbar appears. I want the menu to, on hover, overlap the stuff underneath it.

---

Here is my Javascript code (forget this part):

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
      
      var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
        title: "Menu",
        format: "dropdown",
        sticky: false
      }, options);

      return this.each(function() {
        cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + settings.title + '</div>');
        $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function(){
          $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
          var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
          if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) { 
            mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
          }
          else {
            mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
            if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
              mainmenu.find('ul').show();
            }
          }
        });

        cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');

        multiTg = function() {
          cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
          cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
            if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
              $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
            }
            else {
              $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
            }
          });
        };

        if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
        else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');

        if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

        resizeFix = function() {
          if ($( window ).width() > 768) {
            cssmenu.find('ul').show();
          }

          if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
            cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
          }
        };
        resizeFix();
        return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);

      });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
    title: "Menu",
    format: "multitoggle"
  });

  $("#cssmenu").prepend("<div id='menu-line'></div>");

var foundActive = false, activeElement, linePosition = 0, menuLine = $("#cssmenu #menu-line"), lineWidth, defaultPosition, defaultWidth;

$("#cssmenu > ul > li").each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    activeElement = $(this);
    foundActive = true;
  }
});

if (foundActive === false) {
  activeElement = $("#cssmenu > ul > li").first();
}

defaultWidth = lineWidth = activeElement.width();

defaultPosition = linePosition = activeElement.position().left;

menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
menuLine.css("left", linePosition);

$("#cssmenu > ul > li").hover(function() {
  activeElement = $(this);
  lineWidth = activeElement.width();
  linePosition = activeElement.position().left;
  menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
  menuLine.css("left", linePosition);
}, 
function() {
  menuLine.css("left", defaultPosition);
  menuLine.css("width", defaultWidth);
});

});


});
})(jQuery);


**Here is my CSS code (important!):**
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  background: #83d99e;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#menu-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #009ae1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 13.1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
 
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #009ae1;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-color: #009ae1;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: height .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: height .2s ease;
  -o-transition: height .2s ease;
  transition: height .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 32px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 10px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li,
  #cssmenu ul ul li,
  #cssmenu ul li:hover > ul > li {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.15);
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li,
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul > li,
  #cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
    background: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #000000;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::after,
  #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu-line {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000000;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 3px;
    border-top: 2px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.15);
    height: 52px;
    width: 52px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
    left: 26px;
    display: block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 11px;
    background: #000000;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 21px;
    top: 26px;
    display: block;
    width: 11px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #000000;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
    display: none;
  }
}


And here is my HTML:
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="navStyle.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="navScript.js"></script>
   <title>Navigation Panel</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Bases and Folds</a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Bases</a>
            <ul>
                <li> <a target="_top" href="http://petagami.com/basesfolds/square.html"> Square Base</a></li>
                <li> <a target="_top" href="http://petagami.com/basesfolds/waterbomb.html"> Waterbomb Base </a></li>
                <li> <a target="_top" href="http://petagami.com/basesfolds/kite.html"> Kite Base </a></li>
                <li> <a target="_top" href="http://petagami.com/basesfolds/fish.html"> Fish Base </a></li>
                <li> <a target="_top" href="http://petagami.com/basesfolds/frog.html"> Frog Base </a></li>
                <li> <a target="_top" href="http://petagami.com/basesfolds/diamond.html"> Diamond Base </a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Folds</a>
            <ul>
                <li> <a target="_top" href="http://petagami.com/basesfolds/mountain.html"> Mountain Fold </a></li>
                <li> <a target="_top" href="http://petagami.com/basesfolds/valley.html"> Valley Fold </a></li>
                <li> <a target="_top" href="http://petagami.com/basesfolds/petal.html"> Petal Fold </a></li>
                <li> <a target="_top" href="http://petagami.com/basesfolds/reverse.html"> Reverse Fold </a></li>
                <li> <a target="_top" href="http://petagami.com/basesfolds/outreverse.html"> Oustide-Reverse Fold </a></li>
                <li> <a target="_top" href="http://petagami.com/basesfolds/blintz.html"> Blintz Fold </a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="http://petagami.com/easy.html" target="_top">  Easy Origami </a></li><li>
        <a href="http://petagami.com/modular.html" target="_top">  Modular Origami </a></li><li>
        <a href="http://petagami.com/animals.html" target="_top">  Origami Animals <br> </a></li><li>
        <a href="http://petagami.com/birds.html" target="_top"> Origami Birds </a></li><li>
        <a href="http://petagami.com/index.html" target="_top"> Model Index </a></li><li>
        <a href="http://petagami.com/tradtional.html" target="_top"> Traditional Origami </a></li><li>
        <a href="http://petagami.com/marksym.html" target="_top"> Markings and Symbols </a></li><li>
            
</ul>
</div>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Your question refers to an **object** tag, but I don't see one anywhere else in your question or in your HTML.  For drop-down menus, you will need the menus themselves **position: absolute** and relative to the menu bar with an appropriate **z-index**.  This will allow them to float over the other content when they are visible and should not cause any scroll bars or relayout.

Comment: For z-index, read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index.  Keep in mind it only works for "positioned" elements (e.g. `position: absolute`, `position: fixed`).

Comment: Why do we have so many things that say "Run Code Snippet" that doesn't do anything when you run it?  Is this people not understanding how to post runnable or not runnable code?

Comment: It does work! All you do is click full screen, and you'll get what I'm talking about!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give `overflow: visible;` to cssmenu